# Ubuntu blackscreen after grub

Tags: compiz, graphics

After first viewing Compiz Cube Ubuntus graphics driver crashs and after that I turned the power of and restarted it but now there is a blackscreen after grub loader.

It still works with Windows or older kernel versions with Vesa drivers.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds to me like a graphics driver issue.  I had this issue before and worked around it, removing the graphics driver in recovery on start up.

Comment: Thank you reinstalling the graphics driver is a good idea. but how did you do it exactly You can start up in Graphics recovery mode but the usual drivers aren't released and you can't change the settings there. I could have used a beta graphics driver who is uncompatible with Compiz fusion cube

Comment: shall I do it over command line

Answer (score 0):

For me it Worked by doing CTRL+ALT+F1 then

sudo uninstall flgrx*

then i did

sudo install flgrx-updates

then

rebooted

For me it was a problem after I added my AMD Radeon Graphic card. The problem I think is when I do updates that cause problems with the AMD driver I downloaded. I think that you shouldn't update your ubuntu often if you're going to play on it. You should wait for any new driver to come out then uninstall the old one upgrade ubuntu install the new one. Or like a friend of mine was saying you could update but exclude your graphic card drivers from the update.

My Radeon Graphic card is the R7 Series. Also Latest.